# Rails Rspec redirect_to bouncing to root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec2

I am working on a controller test in Rspec2, Rails 3, basically i have a edit action in a communications controller so if someone wants to edit a bulk email they can in draft mode. if it has been approved or sent it cant be edited.

my controller looks like this

```
class CommunicateController < ApplicationController
before_filter :setup

require_role 'view_communication'
#require_role 'edit_communication', :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy] Role not implemented
require_role 'approve_communication', :only => :approve
require_role 'send_communication', :only => :distribute

 ...

# GET /communications/1/edit
def edit
  if @communication.status == 'Sent' || @communication.status == 'Approved'
    flash[:error] = 'Cannot edit communication once it has been either approved or sent.'
    redirect_to(communicate_path(@communication))
 end
end

 ...

private
  def setup
    @communication = current_account.communications.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
  end
end
```

now it works in production and everything is cool. the issue is now when i have to test it.

my test looks like this:

```
describe CommunicateController, "#edit" do
  context "when i am editing a pre approved bulk email" do
  before(:each) do
    @account = FactoryGirl.create(:account)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:superuser, :accounts => [@account])
    controller.stub(:current_account).and_return(@account)
    @supplier = FactoryGirl.create(:supplier, :account => @account)
    @other_supplier = FactoryGirl.create(:supplier, :account => @account)
    @supplier_report = FactoryGirl.create(:supplier_report, :reportable => @account)
    @communicate = FactoryGirl.create(:communication, :account => @account, :supplier_report => @supplier_report)
    controller.stub(:setup).and_return(@communicate)
  end

  it "denies edit access if the bulk email is sent" do
    @communicate.status = 'Sent'
    get :edit, :id => @communicate.id 
    response.should redirect_to(communicate_path(@communicate))
  end

  it "denies edit access if the bulk email has been approved" do
    @communicate.status = 'Approved'
    get :edit, :id => @communicate.id
    response.should redirect_to(communicate_path(@communicate))
  end

  it "allows edits to Draft bulk email" do
    @communicate.status = 'Draft'
    get :edit, :id => @communicate.id
    response.should redirect_to(edit_communicate_path)
  end

 end
end
```

as you can see setting up the environment for this particular test is quite complex with all the requirements. but when i run the test it gives me the following error:

```
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(communicate_path(@communicate))
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/communicate/1> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>
```

but for all three tests the same error. so the code is working and the test seems to be looking for the correct route, i just dont know why its looking for the root route.

sorry if this is a simple mistake i have only been programming in rails for a few months this is in fact my first controller test in rspec so i am not sure what to look for or if my tests are even in good shape.

any help or guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: Please include `setup` (which you stub here: `controller.stub(:setup).and_return(@communicate)`) and whatever `before_filter`s you have defined in your controller.

Comment: cool i added all that in the controller section of the question. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like

```
grep -ri "redirect_to root_path" ./
```

inside your app directory, you can see where do you have redirects to the root path and try debugging with that

are those actions actually being called? put some "print 'enters!'" at the begining of the edit action, i guess it won't print anything on console because it's not getting even there, if that's the case you probably have some before_filter or require_role or something that you are missing on your test

by the way (as you also ask if your spec is in good shape), you should mock your models and stub the methods that you need, something like

(on the controller)

```
def edit
  unless @communication.can_edit?
    flash[:error] = 'Cannot edit communication once it has been either approved or sent.'
    redirect_to(communicate_path(@communication))
  end
end
```

(on the model)

```
def can_edit?
  ('Sent','Approved').include? status
end
```

(and then on the spec)

```
before(:each) do
  account = mock(:account)
  controller.stub(:current_account).and_return(account)
  communication = mock(:communication)
  communication.stub(:can_edit? => false) #you can override this with true on the allow test
  controller.stub(:setup).and_return(communication)
end
```

and then you move those two deny tests (sent and approved) to the communication specs (it 'returns false if status is Sent' do... etc) and your controller test should be "it 'rdenies access if the communication can not be edited' do"

hope it helps

EDIT: also, I think your spec will if you just use @communication on your controller's actions, you need some helper method like:

```
def current_communication
  @communication
end
```

since you are stubbing the setup method, the @communication assignment is never executed and @communication would be nil if you use it directly

Comment: thanks a lot with the help in debugging i am going to take a look at your suggestions now. but thanks for taking the time to take a look :)

Comment: there was a filter that i was missing and the stub that i had on the :setup didnt need to be there. silly mistakes. thank you